# The anchor #top on subpages send to index page

Tags: html, anchor

I have anchor on subpages:

```
<a name="#top">&nbsp;</a>

<a href="#top">Back to top</a>
```

It works on the index page
but it doesn't work on the subpages.

Link always - `site.com/#top`

Maybe it's problem with JavaScript (for example, Fancybox,etc)

**Update:** Fixed - `<base href="site.com/" />` in `<head>`

Comment: Don't most modern browsers allow you to use #top without an explicit named anchor at the top anyway?

Comment: <a name="top">&nbsp;</a> where you have  placed this tag in index.php or header.php put it in your header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be like this? (without the # on the name)

```
<a name="top">&nbsp;</a>

<a href="#top">Back to top</a>
```

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
<div id="top">Some content</div>

<a href="#top">Back to top</a>
```

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what do you mean?  What happens when you click on the "Back to top" link?

Comment: if I click on the "Back to top" on site.com/page.html I see site.com/#top

Comment: Are you sure you have `href="#top"`?  Or did you do `href="/#top"`?

Comment: 'href="#top"'. And if I use <a href="#"></a> I open index page, but not current page

Comment: Are you using `<base href="site.com/" />` in your head?